# How do I find a certain subset of the binomial coefficient

Tags: arrays, algorithm, combinations

Let's suppose we have an array with length n. We'll call this array

```
keys[n] = {...}
```

What I am looking for is a certain array of subsets given by "n choose 3". We'll call this

```
combination[?][3] = {...}
```

This array needs to meet the following criteria:

- Each subset of length 2 of the 3 keys in each element in array
  combination ("3 choose 2") has to appear at least in one other
  element in combination
- Every key has to appear in at least one element in combination
  (actually in two elements because of the previous criterium)
- The length of combination has to be as small as possible (so out of
  all solutions that satisfy the above two criteria, we need to pick
  one with minimum length)
- Optional: combination is random everytime but still at minimum length
- Optional: No subset of length 2 of the 3 keys in each element in
  array combination ("3 choose 2") appears particularly more often than
  others.

Here's an example:

1. Let keys[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};
2. "4 choose 3" yields the following 10 subsets: {1,2,3}, {1,2,4}, {1,2,5}, {1,3,4}, {1,3,5}, {1,4,5}, {2,3,4}, {2,4,5}, {2,3,5}, {3,4,5}
3. So one solution would be: {1,2,3}, {1,2,4}, {1,3,4}, {2,3,5}, {2,4,5}, {3,4,5} (at least I didn't find a shorter one)

I've been trying to solve this problem all day. I only managed to come up with one really convoluted algorithm that doesn't even work.

Does anyone know how to solve this or even just what you might call this problem?

Comment: Is `2` fixed or a parameter? (I assume that `3` is a parameter, but I don't know what `6 choose 4` would mean. Each subset of length 3 appears twice? Each subset of length 2 appears twice? Depends?    )

Comment: Also `keys[4] = { set of *5* things }` is just wrong. Either get rid of the set, and just let it be the first `n` integers, or get rid of `n`, replacing it with the length of `keys`.

Comment: True, keys[4] is a typo.

Comment: @rici This is quite a difficult problem to explain. 2 and 3 are not paremeters but fixed values. So mathematically 4 choose 3 would give you the amount of possible unique subsets of a set of 4 elements with length 3. Of course it only gives you the number not the actual set of sets. But calculating those sets is not hard. A brute force solution could do that in O(n^3) but I'm not worried about speed here. What I want is to eliminate as many of those subsets as possible while makíng sure this holds: For each subset of length 3 you look at each subset of length 2 in there.

Comment: ...continung    None of those subsets of length 2 can appear exactly once. That is not within the set they are orignally from but from all sets. Looking at my example: The first subset is {1,2,3} this has subsets of length 2: {1,2},{1,3},{2,3}. Looking at {1,2} now for instance, we can see that it also is a subset of another set namely {1,2,4}. This has to hold for all subsets of length 2 of those subsets of length 3.

Comment: I know how to solve this in time `3^(n choose 2)`.  I'm guessing that is slower than you want.

Comment: @btilly no no, I don't care how slow it is. I just need a solution. Any working solution is welcome :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the original solution to a single cover (oops).

Some solutions are more likely than others, but it is still pretty random.  It is fast if not a lot of backtracking happens.  So 13, for example, runs fast.  But 8 runs slowly because the shortest solution has 11 triples, and it has to fail at 10 over and over again before it accepts that.

The idea is an A* search for the shortest possible solution.  With some technical details explained in the code.

Note that it found the following solution for 5: `[[1, 2, 5], [1, 3, 4], [2, 3, 5], [2, 4, 5]]`  This is shorter than you had.

```
import math
import heapq
import random

def min_cover (n):
    # Small helper function.
    def next_pair(pair):
        i, j = pair
        if j < n:
            return [i, j+1]
        elif i+1 < n:
            return [i+1, i+2]
        else:
            raise StopIteration

    # Another small helper function.
    def pair_in(pair, groups):
        i, j = pair
        while groups is not None:
            if i in groups[0] and j in groups[0]:
                return True
            groups = groups[1]
        return False

    numbers = [_ for _ in range(1, n+1)]
    # Queue will be a priority queue of:
    # [
    #    min_pairs_at_finish,
    #    neg_pair,
    #    calculation_for_min_pairs_at_finish,
    #    random_to_avoid_more_comparisons,
    #    last_pair,
    #    [triple, [triple, [triple, ...[None], ...]]]
    # ]
    #
    # The difference between min_pairs and its calculation
    # is subtle.  In the end, the number of pairs is a
    # multiple of 3.  So if we've calculated a minimum
    # of 10 airs, we ACTUALLY can't finish with less than 12.
    #
    # The reason for the ordering is as follows.
    #
    #     min_pairs_at_finish: We want as few as possible.
    #     neg_pair: Prefer continuing solutions that are far along.
    #     calculation_for_min_pairs_at_finish: Closer to done is better
    #     random_to_avoid_more_comparisons: Comparing complex data
    #       is slow.  Don't.  Bonus, this randomizes the answer!
    #     last_pair: Where to continue from.
    #     groups: The solution so far. This data structure efficiently
    #       reuses memory between different partial solutions.
    #
    queue = [[0, [-1, -1], n*(n-1)/2, 0, [1, 1], None]]
    while 0 < len(queue):
        min_cost, neg_pair, min_calc_cost, r, pair, groups = heapq.heappop(queue)
        try:
            pair = next_pair(pair)
            while pair_in(pair, groups):
                pair = next_pair(pair)

            for k in numbers:
                if k != pair[0] and k != pair[1]:
                    extra = 0
                    if pair_in([pair[0], k], groups):
                        extra += 1
                    if pair_in([pair[1], k], groups):
                        extra += 1
                    next_item = [
                        3 * math.ceil((min_cost + extra)/3),
                        [-pair[0], -pair[1]],
                        min_cost + extra,
                        random.random(),
                        pair,
                        [sorted([pair[0], pair[1], k]), groups],
                    ]
                    heapq.heappush(queue, next_item)
        except StopIteration:
            answer = []
            while groups is not None:
                answer.append(groups[0])
                groups = groups[1]
            return list(reversed(answer))

print(min_cover(5))
queue = [[0, n*(n-1)/2, 0, [1, 1], None]]
while 0 < len(queue):
    min_cost, min_calc_cost, r, pair, groups = heapq.heappop(queue)
    try:
        pair = next_pair(pair)
        while pair_in(pair, groups):
            pair = next_pair(pair)

        for k in numbers:
            if k != pair[0] and k != pair[1]:
                extra = 0
                if pair_in([pair[0], k], groups):
                    extra += 1
                if pair_in([pair[1], k], groups):
                    extra += 1
                next_item = [
                    3 * math.ceil((min_cost + extra)/3),
                    min_cost + extra,
                    random.random(),
                    pair,
                    [sorted([pair[0], pair[1], k]), groups],
                ]
                heapq.heappush(queue, next_item)
    except StopIteration:
        answer = []
        while groups is not None:
            answer.append(groups[0])
            groups = groups[1]
        return list(reversed(answer))

 print(min_cover(5))
```

---

And here is a solution to the double cover problem that was actually wanted using the same technique.

```
import math
import heapq
import random

def min_double_cover (n):
    # Small helper function.
    def next_pair(pair):
        i, j = pair
        if j < n:
            return [i, j+1]
        elif i+1 < n:
            return [i+1, i+2]
        else:
            raise StopIteration

    # Another small helper function.
    def double_pair_in(pair, groups):
        i, j = pair
        answer = 0
        while groups is not None:
            if i in groups[0] and j in groups[0]:
                answer += 1
                if 2 <= answer:
                    return True
            groups = groups[1]
        return False

    def triple_in(triple, groups):
        i, j, k = triple
        while groups is not None:
            if i in groups[0] and j in groups[0] and k in groups[0]:
                return True
            groups = groups[1]
        return False

    numbers = [_ for _ in range(1, n+1)]
    # Queue will be a priority queue of:
    # [
    #    min_pairs_at_finish,
    #    neg_pair,
    #    calculation_for_min_pairs_at_finish,
    #    random_to_avoid_more_comparisons,
    #    last_pair,
    #    [triple, [triple, [triple, ...[None], ...]]]
    # ]
    #
    # The difference between min_pairs and its calculation
    # is subtle.  In the end, the number of pairs is a
    # multiple of 3.  So if we've calculated a minimum
    # of 10 airs, we ACTUALLY can't finish with less than 12.
    #
    # The reason for the ordering is as follows.
    #
    #     min_pairs_at_finish: We want as few as possible.
    #     neg_pair: Prefer continuing solutions that are far along.
    #     calculation_for_min_pairs_at_finish: Closer to done is better
    #     random_to_avoid_more_comparisons: Comparing complex data
    #       structures is slow.  Don't.
    #     last_pair: Where to continue from.
    #     groups: The solution so far. This data structure efficiently
    #       reuses memory between different partial solutions.
    #
    queue = [[0, [-1, -2], n*(n-1), 0, [1, 2], None]]
    while 0 < len(queue):
        min_cost, neg_pair, min_calc_cost, r, pair, groups = heapq.heappop(queue)
        try:
            while double_pair_in(pair, groups):
                pair = next_pair(pair)

            for k in numbers:
                if k != pair[0] and k != pair[1] and not triple_in([pair[0], pair[1], k], groups):
                    extra = 0
                    if double_pair_in([pair[0], k], groups):
                        extra += 1
                    if double_pair_in([pair[1], k], groups):
                        extra += 1
                    next_item = [
                        3 * math.ceil((min_cost + extra)/3),
                        [-pair[0], -pair[1]],
                        min_cost + extra,
                        random.random(),
                        pair,
                        [sorted([pair[0], pair[1], k]), groups],
                    ]
                    heapq.heappush(queue, next_item)
        except StopIteration:
            answer = []
            while groups is not None:
                answer.append(groups[0])
                groups = groups[1]
            return list(reversed(answer))

print(min_double_cover(5))
```

This time I couldn't run it for 8 at all.   No clue why not.  But lots of other numbers are fast.

---

At the expense of a potentially incorrect answer, here is a change to make it finish:

```
...
   queue = [[0, [-1, -2], n*(n-1), 0, [1, 2], None]]
    min_pairs = 3*math.ceil(n*(n-1)/3)
    threshold = 1000000
    next_threshold = threshold
    while 0 < len(queue):
        if next_threshold < len(queue):
            print("Threshold reached", next_threshold)
            min_pairs += 3
            for x in queue:
                x[0] = max(min_pairs, x[0])
            heapq.heapify(queue)
            next_threshold += threshold
        min_cost, neg_pair, min_calc_cost, r, pair, groups = heapq.heappop(queue)
...
                    next_item = [
                        max(min_pairs, 3 * math.ceil((min_cost + extra)/3)),
                        [-pair[0], -pair[1]],
                        min_cost + extra,
                        random.random(),
                        pair,
                        [sorted([pair[0], pair[1], k]), groups],
                    ]
...
```

---

And I found a bug.  The following should now be correct.

The numbers where it couldn't figure it out fast, like 8, seem to be the ones where it has to backtrack to a larger number of triples.  If you get the threshold message once, then the answer is possibly off by 1 but probably is right.  If you get it twice, ditto.

```
import math
import heapq
import random

def min_double_cover (n):
    # Small helper function.
    def next_pair(pair):
        i, j = pair
        if j < n:
            return [i, j+1]
        elif i+1 < n:
            return [i+1, i+2]
        else:
            raise StopIteration

    # Another small helper function.
    def double_pair_in(pair, groups):
        i, j = pair
        answer = 0
        while groups is not None:
            if i in groups[0] and j in groups[0]:
                answer += 1
                if 2 <= answer:
                    return True
            groups = groups[1]
        return False

    def triple_in(triple, groups):
        i, j, k = triple
        while groups is not None:
            if i in groups[0] and j in groups[0] and k in groups[0]:
                return True
            groups = groups[1]
        return False

    numbers = [_ for _ in range(1, n+1)]
    # Queue will be a priority queue of:
    # [
    #    min_pairs_at_finish,
    #    neg_pair,
    #    calculation_for_min_pairs_at_finish,
    #    random_to_avoid_more_comparisons,
    #    last_pair,
    #    [triple, [triple, [triple, ...[None], ...]]]
    # ]
    #
    # The difference between min_pairs and its calculation
    # is subtle.  In the end, the number of pairs is a
    # multiple of 3.  So if we've calculated a minimum
    # of 10 pairs, we ACTUALLY can't finish with less than 12.
    #
    # The reason for the ordering is as follows.
    #
    #     min_pairs_at_finish: We want as few as possible.
    #     neg_pair: Prefer continuing solutions that are far along.
    #     calculation_for_min_pairs_at_finish: Closer to done is better
    #     random_to_avoid_more_comparisons: Comparing complex data
    #       structures is slow.  Don't.
    #     last_pair: Where to continue from.
    #     groups: The solution so far. This data structure efficiently
    #       reuses memory between different partial solutions.
    #
    queue = [[0, [-1, -2], n*(n-1), 0, [1, 2], None]]
    min_pairs = 3*math.ceil(n*(n-1)/3)
    threshold = 100000
    next_threshold = threshold
    while 0 < len(queue):
        if next_threshold < len(queue):
            print("Threshold reached", next_threshold)
            min_pairs += 3
            for x in queue:
                x[0] = max(min_pairs, x[0])
            heapq.heapify(queue)
            next_threshold += threshold
        min_cost, neg_pair, min_calc_cost, r, pair, groups = heapq.heappop(queue)
        try:
            while double_pair_in(pair, groups):
                pair = next_pair(pair)

            for k in numbers:
                if k != pair[0] and k != pair[1] and not triple_in([pair[0], pair[1], k], groups):
                    extra = 0
                    if double_pair_in([pair[0], k], groups):
                        extra += 1
                    if double_pair_in([pair[1], k], groups):
                        extra += 1
                    next_item = [
                        max(min_pairs, 3 * math.ceil((min_calc_cost + extra)/3)),
                        [-pair[0], -pair[1]],
                        min_calc_cost + extra,
                        random.random(),
                        pair,
                        [sorted([pair[0], pair[1], k]), groups],
                    ]
                    heapq.heappush(queue, next_item)

        except StopIteration:
            answer = []
            while groups is not None:
                answer.append(groups[0])
                groups = groups[1]
            return list(reversed(answer))

print(min_double_cover(8))
```

Comment: The problem with the example you provided is that for instance the subsets {1,2} and {1,3} only appear once, i.e. there is no other triple that contains 1 and 2 or 1 and 3. Which means that the first condition doesn't hold. Maybe a different way of putting that condition is that you shouldn't be able to unambiguously identify a triple unless you have all three elements. If I for instance have 1 and 2, like in your example, I would already be able to that that {1,2,3} is the only triple that could match that subset of {1,2}. What should happen is that there should be at least on other triple.

Comment: @Yakuwari Oops.  Sorry for solving the wrong problem.  I've offered up an amended version that looks like it should work for the problem that you were looking for.

Comment: Okay, this seems to work. I ran it through my test program for a couple of values and it looks good. Here's an example for n = 10:
Single combos: 0
Subset count: 30
Identical subsets: 0
Key "1" is used 9 times
Key "2" is used 9 times
Key "3" is used 9 times
Key "4" is used 9 times
Key "5" is used 9 times
Key "6" is used 9 times
Key "7" is used 9 times
Key "8" is used 9 times
Key "9" is used 9 times
Key "10" is used 9 times
Like you said with the number 8 it doesn't seem to terminate for certain numbers but that is fine for my use case. Thank you, I'll accept this answer

Comment: @Yakuwari I added a way to finish for hard numbers like 8. I can't prove that it gives correct answers, but I believe that it does.

Comment: thanks for the edition. I ran it through my test program for a couple of values and it looks good. No need for a proof. My brain shuts off when I hear the word proof anyways ;)